# Pretty url not working at my products page

Tags: mysql, .htaccess, url

i am new at working with pretty urls , i have been reading but it just seems super hard to me...

I have this URL:

http://mywebsite.com/producto?id_producto=240

And i want to get something like this

http://mywebsite.com/producto/name-of-the-product

I have been trying a lot of combinations on my .htacces but anything is working, do i have to write the name of every product to make their new URL or can i get that name by sql ?

TY

Comment: You should share with us what you have tried so far in order to get proper help.

Comment: Ok sorry , i think that i should do something similar to this to change my URL to one a bit more clean with numbers.

RewriteRule    ^products/([0-9]+)/?$    producto.php?id_producto_id=$1    [NC,L]    

But i am lost when i have to do it for names , how do i take the name of every product of my databes ?